# How to get specific property from contact form 7 (WordPress) object?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am very new to programming and I would like to extract and save the email address of the person who use my contact form 7.

I am able to extract the contact form id by using

```
function action_wpcf7_mail_failed( $contact_form ) { 

   $aet_formid = $contact_form->id; // this returns the id of the contact form

}
```

but when I use

```
$aet_form_email = $contact_form->post_author_email; // this returns null
```

May I know which property should I use to get the email that the user has entered into the form?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Your question is lacking some details which would help provide more context. To what hooks are you attaching your function, and what is the form field you're trying to capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this to your function:

```
 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance(); 
 $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
```

the `$posted_data` variable hold all values you need.